# Overflow in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm completely new at VBA but my teacher set us a homework and I have to do a kind of ComboBox that when I choose an option, the results of that option are displayed in an Excel cell. To be honest, I did what my 6 hours of knowledge let me do.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim w As Double
    Dim T As Double
    Dim P As Double
    Dim R As Double
    Dim Tc As Double
    Dim Pc As Double
    Dim Tr As Double
    Dim Pr As Double
    Dim B0 As Double
    Dim B1 As Double
    Dim Z As Double
    Dim x As Double
    Dim y As Double
    
    T = Cells(3, 4).Value
    P = Cells(3, 5).Value
    R = 0.08314

    Dim selectedOption As String
    selectedOption = ComboBox1.Value

    If selectedOption = "N2" Then
        Tc = 126.2
        Pc = 34
        Tr = T / Tc
        Pr = P / Pc
        
    If x <> 0 And Not IsNull(x) Then
    x = WorksheetFunction.Round((0.422 / (Tr ^ (1.6))), 14)
    Else
    x = 0
    End If
    
    If y <> 0 And Not IsNull(y) Then
    y = WorksheetFunction.Round((0.172 / (Tr ^ (4.2))), 14)
    Else
    y = 0
    End If
    

        B0 = 0.083 - (x)
        B1 = 0.139 - (y)

        Z = 1 + (B0 * (Pr / Tr)) + (w * B1 * (Pr / Tr))

        Cells(3, 6).Value = Z
    End If
        
    If selectedOption = "H2" Then
        ' Realizar cálculos para H2
        ' ...
    Else
        ' Manejar otras opciones si es necesario
        ' ...
    End If

End Sub
```

It's not completed but when I try to run what I have, it says **overflow** but I don't know what to do or IDK if what I'm doing is OK.

Between my friend and I, we tried a different ways to do the ComboBox with all that stuff and even to not do the ComboBox and just make the things so the results can show up, but we get the same **overflow**. From what I read, I think the error is in the `Tr` part but I don't know why:(

Comment: Which line generates the error? SIDENOTES: IsNull has sense only if you assign `Null` for a variable. You use a lot of unnecessary parentheses, which disturb readability.

Comment: You define Cells without object qualifier, which is the activesheet?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid dividing by zero:

```vb
    If IsNull(x) Then
        x = 0
    End If
    If x <> 0  And Tr <> 0 Then
        x = WorksheetFunction.Round((0.422 / (Tr ^ (1.6))), 14)
    Else
        x = 0
    End If
    
    If IsNull(y) Then
        y = 0
    End If
    If y <> 0 And Tr <> 0 Then
        y = WorksheetFunction.Round((0.172 / (Tr ^ (4.2))), 14)
    Else
        y = 0
    End If
    
    B0 = 0.083 - (x)
    B1 = 0.139 - (y)

    If Tr <> 0 Then
        Z = 1 + (B0 * (Pr / Tr)) + (w * B1 * (Pr / Tr))
    Else
        Z = 0
    End If
```

Comment: Divide by zero fires run-time error 11 `Division by 0`. The OP is about `overflow`

Comment: @BlackCat 0/0 gives overflow error

Comment: @cdp You are right.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite dangerous to use `Range, Cells` objects without fully qualified. That means to define the exact place where  the range you want to reach is. If you don't define it, this expression `Cells()` or `Range()` refer to the ActiveSheet, or if the code is placed in a Sheet code module then to the Sheet itself. In your case because (I think) the code is in a Userform module, the expressions refers to the ActiveSheet.